# Shift central point of world map

Tags: coordinate-system

Update: I managed to find a way to add a custom projection. However, the next problem has presented itself. I end up with a line being drawn across my map. Any advice on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Polygons must be divided at the longitude limits in different parts.

Comment: After looking around here for a while, I managed to figure it out. Thank you!